# Automorphisms of the Symmetric Group

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $n > 6$. Show that an automorphism $f: S_{n} \to S_{n}$ (an isomorphism from $S_{n}$ to itself) will map transpositions to transpositions.

---

I'm not sure on how to start with the problem. I was thinking of using the concept of centralizers (in the case of a transposition $(ij)$, the centralizer will be such $\sigma \in S_{n}$ with $\sigma(i), \sigma(j) \in \{i,j\}$) in order to tackle the problem but thus far I haven't been successful. What would be the correct approach?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost the idea.You know that $f((1,2))$ will be an element of order $2$. Whence a product of $k$ disjoint transposition.

Instead of computing the centralizer of $(1,2)$ and $f((1,2))$ try to compute the number of elements in the conjugacy class (it is much easier). Justify that provided that $n\neq 6$ the only possibility for the numbers of conjugates of $(1,2)$ and of conjugates of $f((1,2))$ is to have $k=1$. To be more precise :

> Let $k\geq 1$, denote $T_k$ to be the number of elements conjugated to $(1,2)...(2k-1,2k)$. Show that :
>
> $$T_k=\frac{1}{k!}\begin{pmatrix}n\\2\end{pmatrix}...\begin{pmatrix}n-2k+2\\2\end{pmatrix} $$

Once you have done this, you just need to show that $T_1=T_k$ has for unique solution $k=1$ (provided that $n\neq 6$).

Comment: personally I find computing the order of the centralizer much easier than computing the size of the class, since I can write that down without having to think about it. It's $2^k \times k! \times (n-2k)!$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, computing the cardinal of the conjugacy class boils down to a regular combinatorial argument which is, IMHO, fairly easy and natural. The first combination corresponds to the choice for the first transposition, the second combination correspond to the choice for the second... and so on, while the $k!$ appears because it is unordered. The same kind of combinatorial argument for computing the cardinal of the centralizer works but seems more confusing (to me).

Comment: I guess in the end it depends on whether you find a combinatorial counting argument or a group theoretical argument easier. For the centralizer argument I am using the fact that I am familiar with its structure as a group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Decomposing this centralizer as the direct product of a symmetric group and a wreath product is, by far, more elegant and meaningful than my method, I agree. However, to compute the cardinal, it seems "too much"... Anyway, thank you for your (as always) interesting remark.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why would showing that $T_{1}=T_{k}$ give rise to the result? I'm not sure why the setting of the problem forces $T_{1}=T_{k}$ (and then having as a unique solution $k=1$). For the other remark, how would having the order of the centralizer help in this case? (and, would it refer to the centralizer of $f((1,2))$, say?) How would one go around to computing the centralizer?

Comment: @fogvajarash, For the first question $T_1$ is the cardinal of the conjugacy class of $(1,2)$ and if $f((1,2))$ is a product of $k$ disjoint transpositions then the cardinal of its conjugacy class is $T_k$. Now, since $f$ is an automorphism both cardinals should coincide (you have to verify it but it is not hard) whence if $T_1=T_k$ iff $k=1$ then this imposes $f((1,2))$ to be a transposition.

Comment: @fogvajarash, for the second question. By the first class formula, if I call $Z((1,2))$ the centralizer of $(1,2)$ you have that $|Z((1,2))|\times |\text{ conjugacy class of } (1,2)|=|S_n|$ hence (since we know that $|S_n|=n!$) computing the cardinal of the conjugacy class or of the centralizer is essentially the same. You can check that the formula I gave for $T_k$ and the formula Derek Holt gave for the cardinal of the centralizer of a product of $k$ disjoint transpositions verify the formula I just gave.